# Remapped multimedia keys using xmodmap not triggering event in Linux Mint 20

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, xmodmap

My aim is to remap XF86AudioLowerVolume/XF86AudioRaiseVolume to the mode_switch minus/equal keys using xmodmap.

If the XF86AudioLowerVolume/XF86AudioRaiseVolume are mapped to the first position, the volume down/up event is triggered correctly.

If the same key code is mapped to any other position (the second key or mode_switch or AltGr positions) the key-press is registered (as confirmed by xev), but fails to trigger a system volume down/up event.

Example of what works (first position, key position):

```
!keycode xx = Key KEY mode_switch MODE_SWITCH AltGr ALTGR
keycode  20 = XF86AudioLowerVolume NoSymbol minus underscore
keycode  21 = XF86AudioRaiseVolume NoSymbol equal plus
```

Examples of what doesn't work (second position, KEY position):

```
keycode  20 = minus XF86AudioLowerVolume
```

Second examples of what doesn't work (third position, MODE_SWITCH position):

```
keycode  20 = minus underscore XF86AudioLowerVolume NoSymbol
```

I guess this has something to do with the system intercepting a single key press as opposed to a multi key press, however I'm not sure why this would be the case...

The system is Linux Mint 20, Cinnamon version 4.6.7

Comment: Hi Andrew, what is your desktop environment or window manager? Have you considered directly mapping the keystrokes to an action (say, `amixer -q set Master 5%+` to increase the volume) through the DE/WM instead of mapping them to a key?

Comment: Hey Quasimodo, the system is Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon version 4.6.7. This mapping is the step before embarking on a custom keyboard, so I more want to understand why the system correctly intercepts single key press events and not multi key press events.